# Nautilus keeps re-creating thumbnails

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails

I'm have a thumbnail problem on my *Ubuntu 12.04* machine where my thumbnails won't stay *deleted*.  I've gone through the following steps in an unsuccessful effort to permanently delete old thumbnails:

- In the `dconf/Configuration Editor`, I go to org -> *gnome -> desktop -> thumbnailer* and paste the MIME type into the *value* field of *disable* key.
- In my `.thumbnails` directory, I delete all files.
- Stop *nautilus* using `nautilus –q`.  Then restart *nautilus*.

As soon as I open an image folder, a thumbnail for each image file in this "images" folder gets re-created in the `.thumbnails` folder again.

How does one resolve this behavior of thumbnails getting re-created each time I open an image folder?

Comment: you dont want images having thumbnail ? you want get that kind of image preview

Answer (score 1):

if you want to disable thumbnail feature in nautilus as:

- open nautilus by clicking Files in launcher
- in menu bar click on Edit > Preferences
- then go to Preview tab as show below. "Show thumbnails:" set it to "Never"

  **Note you will not be able to see thumbnail preview for any file type**

[image: nautilus thumbnail feature]